# JQuery show and hide of multiple items

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I'm making a list of items that all have their own attributes and I need to show and hide each one. This code below works, but it fails to display on click for certain numbers of items (usually even numbered amounts 2,4,6 ect). 'item-small' is what is displayed without clicking and 'item-content' displays on click.

```
echo '<div class="item-small"><strong><a>'.$title.'</a>:</strong>'.$description.'</div>';

echo '<div class="item-content">';
    CreateItemCurrent($status, $notes, $description, $title, $type, $url_id, $category);
    ItemButton($list_id, $db);
    NoteCreator($list_id, $db);
    DeleteButton($list_id, $db);
echo '</div>';

echo '<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item-content").hide();

    $("div.item-small").click(function()
    {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (but would like an explanation)

I ended up moving the script outside the php and the loop so it is only used once. I understand it's bad practice but why would repeating the script cause it to fail on even numbered items?

Comment: For one, you'll be adding multiple event on the same element. And you are also starting the script by hiding all elements.